# how to set local languages on spinner values

Tags: java, android

I am new in android looking to develop an app in local language. I need the help from my formers to set my local language Malayalam to spinner value in Android.
I've tried it with typeface, it doesn't meet my requirements on the spinner but it works for `textView` and `EditText`. Also I have the same problem with action bar.

```
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Meera.ttf");
tv1.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

The above code works for `textView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the typeface to spinner also, you can do it in the spinner adapter, try [this](http://hukum-android-lab.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-how-to-change-spinner-items.html)